# My particle board cabinet came apart. How can I fix it?

Tags: repair

It literally just came apart. The hinges are still on but the rest of the cabinet basically fell apart in my hands. It is held together by 3 flat metal pieces in each slat.

Comment: A photo would be helpful, particle board is not very forgiving when it starts to crumble sometimes it can be repaired or patched but we would be guessing and other times it’s toast.

Comment: Need more information.  Was only door fell off or did everything come apart?  Picture of it added to question will help more.

Comment: Make it out of plywood.  A sign in an independent lumber yard years ago ; " friends do not let friends use OSB ". OSB pretty close to particle board.